# IBM Worklight - How to use adapter domain and port properties taken from external file?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I have a web service. Its domain and port can be changed. So I want to read port and domain from file or db. When this information change, I update them in db or file.

Adapter XML:

```
<domain>${adp.hostname}</domain>
<port>${adp.port}</port>
```

worklight.properties:

```
adp.hostname=localhost
adp.port=10080
```

This is working fine. But I'd like to take `adp.hostname` and `adp.port` from file or db.

Comment: Are we talking here about development or production environment WAS? Tomcat?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to remember about adapters is that you **cannot change** in *real-time* any of the properties set in the adapter XML once it is deployed.

Once the adapter is deployed, it is transformed into an object and is stored in memory. At this time, then, you can no longer interact with its "setup".

The only thing you *can* do, is to decide what will be the value of these properties *before* your deploy the adapter. For example, a different set of properties for QA/TEST/UAT/PROD environments...

---

To setup external properties, starting Worklight 6.0 and above, you can read this  documentation topic: [Configuring an IBM Worklight project in production by using JNDI environment entries](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html)

Specifically for Tomcat in its server.xml:

```
<Context docBase="app_context_path" path="/app_context_path">
  <Environment name="publicWorkLightPort" override="false" 
    type="java.lang.String" value="9080"/>
</Context>
```

1. You change `app_context_path` to your project's context (project name)
2. You add `environment` child elements for each property you need

**Important to remember:** these properties must also exist in `worklight.properties`; those will be the default properties, and if using the above example they will be over-written and the environment properties will be used instead.

In the example above you can see that it will replace the default property `publicWorkLightPort`.

Comment: we are talking about the worklight Development Server in Eclipse. But i donr want to set port and domain in worklight.properties. i want to use it like:
"adp.hostname=select domain from DB.domainTable where serviceCode=3"
is it possible?